# How to search using multiple .Where() ? Vue JS & Firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, conditional-statements, where-clause

I want to query search of multiple collections, not just brand. I query directly from cloud firestore

so far I successfully query the brand.

I try to combine also with category and description, but it always fails

I use where() for that to call directly from firebase

```
getExchanges({commit, state}, {searched} = {searched: ''}) {
      commit('resetPagination');
      // Here you want to make a call to firebase and ask for data
      return db
       .collection('exchanges')
       .where('brand', '>=', searched).where('brand', '<=', searched+ '\uf8ff')
       .limit(state.pagination.itemCount)
       .get()
       .then(snapshots => {
         if (snapshots.docs.length === 0) {
            commit('setExchanges', []);
            return []
         }
         const exchanges = snapshots.docs.map(doc => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id}))
         commit('setExchanges', exchanges)
         commit('setLastItem', snapshots.docs[snapshots.docs.length - 1])
         commit('setPreviousFirstItem', snapshots.docs[0])
         return exchanges
        })
```

My field in the exchange collection in the firestore is

- brand
- category
- city

With category, i try to do this

```
.where('brand' || 'category', '>=', searched).where('brand' || 'category', '<=', searched+ '\uf8ff')
```

Do you have some suggestions? that would be amazing

Cheers

Zaid

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do a logical OR query, which is not supported by Firestore.

Comment: You may be interested by this article: https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-combined-two-firestore-queries-to-simulate-a-logical-or-query-27d28a43cb2d *(disclaimer: I'm the author)*

Answer (score 1):

Currently Cloud Firestore does not support "OR" queries. The closest thing you can have is using the "array-contains" and "array-contains-any" queries and explicitly design your data structure to suit the query needs. An alternative would be to use a third party service called [Algolia](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search).

Another point to note is that your code

```
.where('brand' || 'category', '>=', searched).where('brand' || 'category', '<=', searched+ '\uf8ff')
```

is identical to

```
.where('brand', '>=', searched).where('brand', '<=', searched+ '\uf8ff')
```

as `||` operator in javascript returns the second term if the first term is undefined, null, an empty string, an empty array or false and returns the first term otherwise.

Comment: Hi 

Thank you very much for the suggestion 

I will try to use the array-contains-any


Thank you for OR information, now i relazie why it keeps failing 



cheers

Zaid

Comment: hi CRUD DS 

It seems that array-contains-any is not for multiple fields, it is used for multiple value?